# Hibernate: parameter does not exist as a named parameter on Wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, wildfly

I have the following code snippet working with hibernate 4.2.2:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("Usuario.findById");
query.setLong("id", identificadorUsuario);
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT user FROM scsg.model.Usuario user WHERE user.idUsuario=:id
```

And it Works locally. But when I deploy to the server it launches following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter id does not exist as a named parameter in [SELECT user FROM scsg.model.Usuario user WHERE user.idUsuario=:id]
```

Server is a Wildfly server. All POJO clases have their getters and setters. Any help?

Comment: Could you post the setter and getter for id?

Comment: Also, have you tried using setParameter instead of setLong?

Comment: @JamesB With setParameter the exception is the same. Getter and setter:       

    public Long getIdUsuario() {
        return idUsuario;
    }

    public void setIdUsuario(Long idUsuario) {
        this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
    }